# How to keep track of the most popular products

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement a "Popular Products" feature. Basically, every time a Product is viewed, I want to log to the database the number of views of that product. Where do I put the hooks for something like this? I have seen things that are based on building some sort of traffic analytics, but I am looking for ideas that would keep this feature more coupled to the RoR app.

Answer (score 4):

I assume there is a 'view' method in the controller, doing something like

```
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
```

If the product has a 'views' field, you can do something like

```
@product.views = @product.views + 1
@product.save
```

Answer (score 3):

Writing to a `@product.views` counter like @eelco.lempsink.nl says might be a perfectly working basic solution but IMHO there would be significant scalability issues like:

- Doing a DB write on reads will be a pretty significant overload
- If its a big app, there is a high likelihood that views will be getting hit of your server cache

Maybe a more scalable (but very non RoR) solution would be to take server logs and run batch processes to run popularity calculations (like unique per IP etc) and then update this info into a RoR model.

Answer (score 1):

A views field like eelco.lempsink.nl suggested should probably work. And to get the most popular items you add something like:

```
:sort => "views DESC",
```

But make really sure that only views of the item by humans is counted. If the count is encreased each time the item is displayed in the list of popular items, you'll get a feedback loop messing up the popularity system. Allso make sure that webcrawlers is not allowed to change the view status.

Allso you really should consider what you want to measure, the amount of people interested in a product, or the amount fooled by a misleading thumbnail and high popularity ranking into clicking on a product.

If this is a webshop or similar, you're probably better off counting the number of buyers instead of views. That would more correctly measure real interest in the product (because they were actually interested enough to spend money on it), and allso I think *writing* to the database for a view sounds a little unwise (there's massively more views than buys). You'll get better data than a `views` field wich may suffer from feedback problems anyway, because you can have popularity history by selecting the count of `order` rows for a product with timestamp within a certain timeframe. Getting the orders from the last week or so would probably not be so expensive (for very long timespans the result should probably be cached).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're presenting the stuff, and what you really want to do with the views, you might want to punt on this altogether and use something like Google/Microsoft analytics.  They've put a ton of time into their products that will let you see all kinds of info about your traffic over time.

Answer (score 0):

I would say keep track of some stats in a separate table. For example:

products_views

--

product_id
user_id
ip_address
created_at
updated_at

That way you don't have to worry about locking updating the views field in the database if two people are viewing at the same time.  You could then process this table in the background to roll up stats.

Answer (score 0):

I like google analitics for this kinda thing, then use the API to pull the figures into your app.

This negates any "false" reads and theres a ton of other info you can track and log.